# Set element id = javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, playframework, playframework-2.0

So I have an issue that I'm not 100% sure on how to solve. Im looping through a list of strings and creating multiple forms, what I want to do is set the id of the elements to the string minus spaces.
I have a javascript function to remove the spaces

```
function trimWhiteSpaces(name) {
return name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

and below is my current code for generating the forms:

```
@(name: List[String])
```

...

```
@for(name <- names) {
        <td>@name
        @form(routes.Application.makeCall()) {
        <div id="hiddenForm" style="visibility:hidden">
            <input type="text" name="commandID" id="id@name" value="10" />
            <input type="text" name="source" id="sourceCall@name" value="source" />
            <input type="text" name="destination" id="dest@name" value="@name" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Call" id="call@name"/>
        }
}
```

but what I would like to do is:
is something like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Call" id="call{js:timWhiteSpaces(@name)}"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
The other option I have thought that would work would be instead of passing strings pass a new custom objects that has two options. But as I'm not an expert at html/javascript i was wondering if there was a way to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you do it on the server side, as in

```
id="@(name.replace(" ", ""))"
```

Comment: cool thank you very much.
i was abloe to use the following and it worked:

    <input type="text" name="source" id="@name.replace(" ","")" value="source" />